# Hover doesn't work on pesudo classes that has the animation

Tags: html, css

i tried to make this animation so it would pause when i hover on it but every time i do, only the div get paused and the pesudo elements don't so what did i do wrong?
i tried to change the property like making the background color change with hover and it works! so it seems that the problem is something related to the animation but i can't get my hand on it

### This is my Css

```css
.task1 {
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: #fca900 solid 5px;
    border-left: transparent solid 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
            animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
}

.task1::after {
    content: "";
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5px;
    left: 2.5px;
    border: #2090db solid 5px;
    border-top: transparent solid 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
            animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
}

.task1::before {
    content: "";
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border: #e51758 solid 5px;
    border-right: transparent solid 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
            animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    to {
        transform:  rotate(1turn);
    }
}
 
@keyframes rotate {
    to {
        transform:  rotate(1turn);
    }
}

.task1:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
            animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="task1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo elements are styled independently so you need to pause their animations on task1 being hovered as well.

```css
.task1 {
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: #fca900 solid 5px;
  border-left: transparent solid 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
  animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
}

.task1::after {
  content: "";
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5px;
  left: 2.5px;
  border: #2090db solid 5px;
  border-top: transparent solid 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
}

.task1::before {
  content: "";
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: #e51758 solid 5px;
  border-right: transparent solid 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotate linear infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.task1:hover,
.task1:hover::after,
.task1:hover::before {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="task1"></div>
```

Comment: thank you that actually worked! but why when i try to pause the animation for the before element only for example and leaving the rest running it doesn't work?

Comment: Can't say without seeing your code. It should be the same as in this snippet (taking out the hover settings for the task1 and after pseudo elements and leaving just the before element being paused - it worked for me),

Comment: just changed the last part to that and didn't work for me `.task1:hover::before {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}`

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading - going on incorrect. The main element is still rotating, so the pseudo element keeps rotating with it (as pseudo before/after elements are basically part of the element's content). But it doesn't have its own rotation as well. Try making the main element rotate at 10s and remove the before element's rotation on hover and you'll see its rotation speed change. If you wanted the before to stop (or appear to stop) rotating but the main div to carry on you could reverse its animation direction I suppose.

Comment: Oh  i got it now. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because you are only pausing task1 not it's pesudos just do this change to your code

```
.task1::before, .task1::after, .task1:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
            animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!

Comment: please mark as answered and upvote if helped.  Thanks